# Assertion еще есть в джаве?

Tags: java, assertion

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли `assertion` ещё в джаве, и если он ещё есть, то подскажите, в чем ошибка.

```
System.out.println("Enter your Age");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 
int Age = in.nextInt();
 
assert (Age >= 0) : "Negative Age";

System.out.println("your Current Age is:" + Age);
```

Answer (score 5):

Добавьте ключик `-ea` (**e**nable**a**ssertions) в вашу ран конфигурацию (ну либо командную строку). Ассерты заработают.

Документация [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/6jgp65ikq/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо ,все получилось а то я подумала что assertion уже не существуют